# xslt functions to stop repeated code

Tags: xslt, umbraco

Hi I am a complete beginner with xslt and have just started using it as I am building a site with Umbraco.  I was wondering if there was any way of creating functions within xslt so I didn't have to repeat the same thing over.  I have had a look at a few sites but don't really understand it

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:variable name="items" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@isDoc and @level = 1]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']"/>

<!-- The fun starts here -->

<xsl:if test="count($items) &gt; 0">
<ul id="SubNav" class="level{@level}">
  <xsl:for-each select="$items">
  <li>
    <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
    </a>
    <xsl:if test="count(./child::*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']) &gt; 0">
        <ul class="level{@level}">
        <xsl:for-each select="./child::*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
          <li>
            <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
              <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
            </a>
            <xsl:if test="count(./child::*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']) &gt; 0">
                <ul class="level{@level}">
                <xsl:for-each select="./child::*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
                  <li>
                    <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                      <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
            </xsl:if>
          </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:if>
  </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
</xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see foreach node I am reusing the same code to list the children so I was wondering if I could pull this out into a function so I wouldn't have to nest the same code for each level of children I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea in XSLT is to work with templates that match certain nodes in your XML structure. You can even apply the same exact template with different processing instructions using "modes".

I do not know your XML structure but I assume that would be the way to go. Searching in stackoverflow provides information too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/templates+xslt

Comment: Thanks with this information I was able to figure out I needed another template and have made a solution from it

Comment: @Pete: You are welcome. That sounds good. Glad I could help. Best regards, Peter

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 2.0 allows you to write functions which you can invoke from the XPath expressions in your code. For example, you could define

```
<xsl:function name="f:isRelevant" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="node" as="element()"/>
  <xsl:sequence 
    select="count($node/child::*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1'])"/>
</xsl:function>
```

and then you could write, for example

```
<xsl:if test="f:isRelevant(.)">...</xsl:if>
```

If you're on a platform that restricts you to XSLT 1.0, then you're going to have to put up with your code being more verbose. You can use named templates and the xsl:call-template instruction for common chunks of XSLT code, but they aren't nearly as convenient as functions, for example you can't call them within the test expression of xsl:if as in this example.